# Sphinx Building Index Improvement

Tags: mysql, sphinx, indexing

Hey guys, I have a question about Sphinx. I use Sphinx to index the full-text searches for my sites, and it works like a dream. At this point in time it takes about 30 minutes to create the indexes for all my databases. This is fine as I only run the indexing script once every hour.

But the databases are getting bigger quickly, and soon I'm afraid the databases will be so big, it wont be able to do the process in 1 hour. Of course I can run it only once every 2 hours, but this is not ideal.

**Now my question:** Is sphinx rebuilding the entire indexes every time the script runs, or does it only add the newest items that were recently added to the database (since the last index run)?

My feeling says, that it totally rebuilds it.

In case that is true, is it also possible to ONLY the items that were not in it already? Could this make the indexing time a lot shorter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See Delta index updates: http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#delta-updates

The idea is to maintain two indexes: **main** and **delta**. You only need to build the index for newly added/update contents into the **delta** index, and merge back to the **main** index periodically.

Answer (score 0):

split your index

main  and delta is  the  most conventional if you can identify easily  new/updated rows.

if not split can serve you to reindex many "parts" in same time.

with an index of 180M (randomly updated) where I had average of 5K new rows every hour.

My solution was

22 partial indexes  (because 24 core in server)
20 partial indexes equals
2 "delta" indexes

by script I compute start and end id of each part with this rule

last delta = start from first id  created today
other delta = start from first id  created yesterday end with first id  created today

for partial index it was basically based on

- START position-1 * ((first id  created yesterday)/20 )
- END   position * ((first id  created yesterday)/20 )

last delta was rebuild in few seconds,
20 first block  was build in  10 minutes

before, with the monolitic version the full index was rebuild in 4 hours (but there was only 90M row and sphinx 0.9.9)